# URI params in mulerequester

Tags: mule, mule-component

I recently worked with mulerequester and used "connector" and "selector" in the uri params as shown below.

```
<mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="wmq://REPLY.QUEUE?connector=wmqConnector&amp;selector=JMSCorrelationID%3D'#[sessionVars.myCorrelationId]'" doc:name="Mule Requester" timeout="120000"/>
```

Is there a list of all acceptable uri params for mulerequester? I couldn't find that in any documentation. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the transport. Here is the info on how to construct Mule endpoint URIs. Here are the three common ones:

connector - The name of an existing connector to use for this endpoint URI.

transformers - Defines a comma-separated list of transformers to configure on the endpoint.

address - Explicitly sets the endpoint address to the specified value and ignores all other info in the URI.

JMS have selector and HTTP will have method for example.

Here is the reference:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE2USER/Mule+Endpoint+URIs